# No rule to make target 'SGX/linux-sgx-driver'. when installing Linux-SGX-Driver

Tags: linux, sgx

When installing Intel-SGX-Driver(https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx-driver), I got this error:

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-107-generic/build M=/home/niujuxin/Intel SGX/linux-sgx-driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-107-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'SGX/linux-sgx-driver'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-107-generic'
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

How could I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error `make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'SGX/linux-sgx-driver'.  Stop.` comes from your path containing a space.

In `Makefile`, Change the line

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

by

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M="$(PWD)" modules
```

And you can do the same for the installation rule.

---

Or simplier, change the file path

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This problem has been solved.